# Blazorise line chart is only plotting part of the dataset

Tags: c#, blazor, blazorize

**The Setup**

I have a Microsoft Blazor web application (server-side) that uses the [Blazorise line chart](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/chart) component to display a simple graph that is supposed to show 27 data points. (Blazorise Charts are a Blazor wrapper for [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/)).

Development environment:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2022
- .NET 7

**The Problem**

The graph only shows the first 10 data points. The remaining 17 are never shown, as you can see in the screenshot below:
[image: screenshot of the line graph]
Hovering over the datapoints on the graph and checking the values displayed in the tooltips confirms that the 10 visible Y-values really do correspond to the first 10 items in the dataset, so it is plotting those correctly but is just ignoring the remaining 17 values.

I have confirmed that the dataset applied to the Blazorise graph component does indeed contain 27 values, and there are also 27 labels, as is visible in the screenshot above.

Users can select from approximately 20 raw data records. In each case a new dataset is computed for the graph, so each raw data record produces a different graph. Irrespective of the user selection, only the first 10 data points are displayed.

Chrome's dev tools shows no client-side errors.

**What would resolve the problem?**

The graph shows all 27 data points.

**Code extracts**

Here is the code that creates the labels and dataset and launches the graph:

```
@using PolarExplorer.Data
@using PolarExplorer.Interfaces

@inject IPolarService PolarService
@inject IOptionsBuilder OptionsBuilder

<Card>
  <CardBody>
    <LineChart @ref="LineChart" TItem="double" Options="OptionsBuilder.Build()" />
  </CardBody>
</Card>

@code {
  private LineChart<double> LineChart { get; set; } = new();

  public async Task DrawChart(PolarData polarData)
  {
    var polar = PolarService.GetPolar(polarData);

    var labels = polar.Select(x => $"{x.Speed:00}").ToList();
    var chartData = polar.Select(x => x.Sink).ToList();

    var dataset = new LineChartDataset<double>
      {
        Label = "Polar",
        Data = chartData,
        BackgroundColor = Colour.Background.Red,
        BorderColor = Colour.Border.Red,
        PointRadius = 2,
        Tension = 0.4f
      };

    await LineChart.Clear();
    await LineChart.AddLabelsDatasetsAndUpdate(labels, dataset);
    
    StateHasChanged();
  }
}
```

Here is the `PolarService` code. This isn't strictly relevant to the current problem but I've included it for context. It takes three points on a parabola, computes the quadratic coefficients and returns a list of data points that lie on the same parabola for plotting.

```
using PolarExplorer.Data;
using PolarExplorer.Interfaces;

namespace PolarExplorer;

public class PolarService : IPolarService
{
  private const int NumberOfDataPoints = 27;
  private const int SpeedStep = 5;
  private const int MinSpeed = 120;
  
  public List<PolarPoint> GetPolar(PolarData polarData)
  {
    var point1 = new PolarPoint(polarData.Speed1, polarData.Sink1);
    var point2 = new PolarPoint(polarData.Speed2, polarData.Sink2);
    var point3 = new PolarPoint(polarData.Speed3, polarData.Sink3);
    var (a, b, c) = CalculateCoefficients(point1, point2, point3);

    var polar = Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfDataPoints)
      .Select(x => x * SpeedStep + MinSpeed)
      .Select(speed => new PolarPoint(speed, a * speed * speed + b * speed + c))
      .ToList();

    return polar;
  }
  
  private static (double A, double B, double C) CalculateCoefficients(PolarPoint point1, PolarPoint point2, PolarPoint point3)
  {
    var denominator = (point1.Speed - point2.Speed) * (point1.Speed - point3.Speed) * (point2.Speed - point3.Speed);
    var a = (point3.Speed * (point2.Sink - point1.Sink) + point2.Speed * (point1.Sink - point3.Sink) + point1.Speed * (point3.Sink - point2.Sink)) / denominator;
    var b = (point3.Speed * point3.Speed * (point1.Sink - point2.Sink) + point2.Speed * point2.Speed * (point3.Sink - point1.Sink) + point1.Speed * point1.Speed * (point2.Sink - point3.Sink)) / denominator;
    var c = (point2.Speed * point3.Speed * (point2.Speed - point3.Speed) * point1.Sink + point3.Speed * point1.Speed * (point3.Speed - point1.Speed) * point2.Sink + point1.Speed * point2.Speed * (point1.Speed - point2.Speed) * point3.Sink) / denominator;

    return (a, b, c);
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the output from `PolarService.GetPolar()`:

[image: Data reom PolarService.GetPolar()]

This is the `PolarPoint` POCO class:

```
namespace PolarExplorer;

public class PolarPoint
{
  public PolarPoint(double speed, double sink)
  {
    Speed = speed;
    Sink = sink;
  }
  
  public double Speed { get; set; }
  public double Sink { get; }
}
```

This is the code that creates the `LineChartOptions` for the chart component:

```
using Blazorise.Charts;
using PolarExplorer.Interfaces;

namespace PolarExplorer;

public class OptionsBuilder : IOptionsBuilder 
{
  public LineChartOptions Build()
  {
    return new LineChartOptions
    {
      AspectRatio = 3,
      Responsive = true,
      Plugins = new ChartPlugins
      {
        Title = new ChartTitle
        {
          Display = true,
          Text = "title goes here",
          Color = "#000000"
        }
      },
      Scales = new ChartScales
      {
        X = new ChartAxis
        {
          Grid = new ChartAxisGridLine
          {
            BorderColor = "#000000",
            Display = true,
            DrawBorder = true,
          },
          AlignToPixels = true,
          Title = new ChartScaleTitle
          {
            Align = "center",
            Text = "Cruising speed (kph)",
            Color = "#000000",
            Display = true
          },
          Ticks = new ChartAxisTicks
          {
            Display = true,
            Major = new ChartAxisMajorTick
            {
              Enabled = true
            }
          }
        },
        Y = new ChartAxis
        {
          Grid = new ChartAxisGridLine
          {
            BorderColor = 0,
            Display = true,
            DrawBorder = true
          },
          Title = new ChartScaleTitle
          {
            Align = "center",
            Text = "Sink rate (m/s)",
            Color = 0,
            Display = true
          },
          Ticks = new ChartAxisTicks
          {
            Display = true,
          },
          BeginAtZero = true,
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

And finally, here is the Index page code, that initiates the entire process:

```
@page "/"


@using PolarExplorer.Interfaces
@using PolarExplorer.Data
@using PolarExplorer.Components

@inject IPolarDataRepository PolarDataRepository

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<GliderSelector GroupedGliders="GroupedGliders" OnSelectedGliderChanged="@(async (gliderId) => await OnSelectedGliderChanged(gliderId))"></GliderSelector>
<PolarDataInfoPanel PolarData="PolarData"></PolarDataInfoPanel>
<ChartPanel @ref="ChartPanel"></ChartPanel>

@code
{
  private List<IGrouping<string, Glider>> GroupedGliders { get; set; } = new();
  private PolarData PolarData { get; set; } = new();
  private ChartPanel ChartPanel { get; set; } = new();

  protected override async void OnInitialized()
  {
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    GroupedGliders = PolarDataRepository
      .GetGliders()
      .OrderBy(glider => glider.ManufacturerName)
      .GroupBy(glider => glider.ManufacturerName)
      .ToList();

    var firstGlider = GroupedGliders
      .First()
      .OrderBy(glider => glider.Model)
      .First();

    PolarData = PolarDataRepository.GetPolarDataById(firstGlider.Id);
  }

  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
  {
    if (firstRender)
    {
      await ChartPanel.DrawChart(PolarData);
    }
  }

  private async Task OnSelectedGliderChanged(int gliderId)
  {
    PolarData = PolarDataRepository.GetPolarDataById(gliderId);
    await ChartPanel.DrawChart(PolarData);
  }
}
```

My `_Host.cshtml` includes this script tag in the body:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>`

**What I have tried:**

- Different browsers (Chrome and Edge)
- Changing the data type from `double` to `decimal`
- Changing the number of datapoints
- Tearing my hair

None of these has changed anything, the first 10 datapoints are the only ones ever displayed.

**In Conclusion**

Any help, including suggestions as to where to look next would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limitation comes from the changes in recent licensing terms. For community and unregistered versions there are now limits implemented. This can be compared on https://blazorise.com/pricing, and are explained under the release notes https://blazorise.com/news/release-notes/140

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, Mladen. I have signed up for an account but the verification email hasn't arrived. Can you help with this?